# How can I create an observable that alternates between two observables

Tags: c#, system.reactive

If I had observables `a` and `b` and I wanted to alternate between the two based on a third observable `c` how would I go about doing that?  The marble diagram would look something like this:

```
a: -a1---------a2----a3--a4------a5--a6-----a7----
b: -b1--b2----b3--b4----------------b5---b6---b7--
c: --------c-----------c--------c----------c------
                    alternate
   -a1--------b3--b4-----a4---------b5---b6-a7----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works nicely:

```
var query =
    a.Publish(pa =>
        b.Publish(pb =>
            c.StartWith("c")
                .Select((x, n) => n % 2 == 0 ? pa : pb)
                .Switch()));
```

I tested using this code:

```
var xs = new []
{
    "a1", "b1", "b2", "c", "b3",
    "a2", "b4", "a3", "c", "a4",
    "c", "a5", "b5", "a6", "b6",
    "c", "a7", "b7",
}
    .ToObservable()
    .Publish();

var a = xs.Where(x => x.StartsWith("a"));
var b = xs.Where(x => x.StartsWith("b"));
var c = xs.Where(x => x.StartsWith("c"));

var query = ...

query.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

xs.Connect();
```

I got this result:

```
a1 
b3 
b4 
a4 
b5 
b6 
a7
```

The `xs.Connect()` was only necessary to make the `xs` observable work as an easy way to generate the three sequences.

And even as the extension method:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Alternate<TSource>(
    this IObservable<TSource> leftSelector,
    bool startLeft,
    IObservable<TSource> left,
    IObservable<TSource> right)
{
    return
        left.Publish(pl =>
            right.Publish(pr =>
                leftSelector.StartWith(default(TSource))
                    .Select((x, n) => (n % 2 == (startLeft ? 0 : 1)) ? pl : pr)
                    .Switch()));
}
```

Comment: Very neat +1. I edited this very slightly into my answer to allow for the possibility of the "Selector" not having alternating values (although `DiscreteUntilChanged` could be used here too).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way, similar idea - it also lets you specify a starting value for the selector.

The key idea is zipping each value stream with the most recent selector value using `Zip` and `MostRecent`. We can then filter each zipped stream based on the selector value and merge them.

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Alternate<TSource>(
    this IObservable<bool> leftSelector,
    bool startLeft,
    IObservable<TSource> left,
    IObservable<TSource> right)
{   
    return leftSelector.Publish(
    selector => 
      Observable.Merge(        
        left.Zip(selector.MostRecent(startLeft), Tuple.Create)
            .Where(l => l.Item2),                      
        right.Zip(selector.MostRecent(startLeft), Tuple.Create)
             .Where(r => !r.Item2)))
      .Select(res => res.Item1);            
}
```

Also, here's Enigmativity's neat approach very slightly tweaked to fit the inputs here:

```
public static IObservable<TSource> Alternate2<TSource>(
    this IObservable<bool> leftSelector,
    bool startLeft,
    IObservable<TSource> left,
    IObservable<TSource> right)
{   
    return
        left.Publish(l =>
            right.Publish(r =>
                leftSelector.StartWith(startLeft)
                    .Select(s => s ? l : r)
                    .Switch()));        
}
```

Comment: Extension method declaration and `Tuple.Create` make this more beautiful than my solution. +1

Comment: I'm curious to know why you're using `this IObservable<bool> leftSelector` when the `c` observable in the question is just producing the same value each time? To make this work you effectively need to convert the equivalent of `IObservable<Unit>` to `IObservable<bool>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Enigmativity No you aren't missing anything. Rather I was employing the dark art of scope creep to add an interesting but wholly unrequested feature; that you might want to decide how c selects the stream rather than just alternating. I was imagining a projection of c applied to produce the bool stream. Did it without thinking really; it's quite similar to a feature I had to build once that did have that requirement now I come to think of it. Anyway, I'll leave it in for interest, but you're right to point out it's superfluous to requirements.

Comment: @JamesWorld - Makes sense. It certainly made the query look even neater. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This solution declares c as `Observable<bool>`

The result `Observable` emits values from a and b based on latest value from  c. Values from a and b are wrapped into a container class for `Merge`

```
var a = Observable.Range(1, 10);
var b = Observable.Range(10, 20);

var merged = a.Select(i => new Container {id = "a", value = i})
              .Merge( b.Select(i => new Container {id = "b", value = i}));

var c = Observable.Return(true); 

var result = merged.CombineLatest( c , (ab, selector ) 
                  => (selector && ab.id == "a") || (!selector && ab.id == "b") ? ab : null)
                   .Where(i => i != null);

public class Container
{
    public string id;
    public int value;
}
```